# How do I remove white space due to position relative of CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a website that will display the image of the product on the left and the specs or features on the right. I've tried using position relative and it does the job done.But the only problem is when I've shifted it beside the image, it has a big white empty space from where it came from and I don't know how to remove it. Please share your knowledge about this and feel free to suggest new techniques to better my script.

I provided a small script below that resembles the website that I'm trying to build for easier analysis.

Here is the code for main.html:

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 65%;
}
#imageStyle {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
#featuresStyle {
  position: relative;
  left: 480px;
  bottom: 870px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="imageStyle">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXMyE-1O_Be_qDQa7YwQGW8DLhNEeNVlOXgKj9BMGdKVsRbSdoYw" />
  </div>
  <div id="featuresStyle">
    <h2>Name: Ibanez M8M</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Price: $30000</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Description: Good Guitar!</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Neck Type: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Body: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Fretboard: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Bridge: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Neck Pickup: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Bridge Pickup: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Hardware Color: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, why did u set #featuresStyle::left to 480px and bottom to 870px ? Are you only looking for a 2x column content with an image on the left column + the description on the right rolumn ? If yes, do you want the content on the right to take the entire width when it's higher than the picture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good time to use flexbox. Have a look.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 65%;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#imageStyle {
  margin: 10px 60px;
}
#featuresStyle {
  margin: 10px 0;
  flex: 1;
}
#featuresStyle h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
/* Just to show it working */

#wrapper {
  background: navy;
}
#featuresStyle {
  background: lime;
}
#imageStyle {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="imageStyle">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXMyE-1O_Be_qDQa7YwQGW8DLhNEeNVlOXgKj9BMGdKVsRbSdoYw" />
  </div>
  <div id="featuresStyle">
    <h2>Name: Ibanez M8M</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Price: $30000</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Description: Good Guitar!</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Neck Type: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Body: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Fretboard: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Bridge: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Neck Pickup: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Bridge Pickup: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
    <h2>Hardware Color: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The colors are just to show where each element is, flexbox will keep it looking nice side by side, you'll notice I gave `#featureStyle` `flex: 1;` that means it will grow and fill the remaining space.

I also added a min-width which means it won't get smaller that 720px.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

using flex is flexible :) try to review this code

```css
#wrapper
{
 border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  width: 65%;
  display:flex;
}

#imageStyle 
{
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex:2;
  
}

#featuresStyle 
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex:4;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
         <div id="imageStyle">
            <img src="Music Store/img/Ibanez Guitars/ibanezM8MStandingPosition.png" />
         </div>

         <div id="featuresStyle">
             <h2>Name: Ibanez M8M</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Price: $30000</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Description: Good Guitar!</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Neck Type: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Body: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Fretboard: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Bridge: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Neck Pickup: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Bridge Pickup: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
             <h2>Hardware Color: Bla Bla Bla</h2>
             <br/>
         </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add float for both and change `left: 800px` on `#featureStyle`vfor better appearance

```
   #imageStyle
{
margin-left: 60px;
float:left;
}

#featuresStyle
{
position: relative;
float: left;
left: 800px;;
bottom: 870px;
}
```

Comment: someone in SO told me to avoid `float`. I agree with him. better yet to use `display:inline-block` or flex instead.

Comment: yeah, it could be the best option

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with float as long as you know what you're doing. Float allow you to do things that you can't do with inline-block or flex, albeit you need to make sure you get rid of the floating properties when you do not need them.

Comment: correct, unfortunately I am not expert in deciding which one to use better. So in coding I will just do _trial and error_ combining all of those

Comment: If you know what you're doing, sure, float is good. But very few people know what they are doing when it comes to CSS, especially floats, even many senior developers. A project riddled with floats is likely poorly coded and very fragile.